# Using move.py to move files in CSV list

Tags: python, django, csv

I am a novice with python. I have images located in a external RAID drive. I want to use a .csv file containing needed images to move only these images from the external RAID.

I have move.py and hasselblad.csv on my desktop.

This is the command example I have been given, but it has not worked, even after filling in the source/destinations:

```
python move.py —csvfile /path/to/hasselblad.csv —src /path/to/source/images —dest /path/to/where/images/should/be/copied
```

The Python file details:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import csv
import sys
import logging

def find(src, fname):

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):

    for f in files:

        logging.debug("compare %s to %s" % (f, fname))

        if f == fname:

            path =  os.path.join(root, f)
            logging.info("%s matches %s" % (path, fname))
            return path

return None

def scan(src):

lookup = {}

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):

    for f in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, f)
        path = os.path.abspath(path)
        lookup[f] = path

return lookup

if __name__ == '__main__':

import optparse

parser = optparse.OptionParser()

parser.add_option('--csvfile', dest='csvfile',
                    help='',
                    action='store')

parser.add_option('--src', dest='src',
                    help='',
                    action='store', default=None)

parser.add_option('--dest', dest='dest',
                    help='',
                    action='store', default=None)

parser.add_option("--verbose", dest="verbose",
                  help="", 
                  action="store_true", default=False)

parser.add_option("--debug", dest="debug",
                  help="", 
                  action="store_true", default=False)

opts, args = parser.parse_args()

if opts.verbose:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

if not os.path.exists(opts.csvfile):
    logging.error("CSV file (%s) does not exist!" % opts.csvfile)
    sys.exit()

if not os.path.isdir(opts.src):
    logging.error("Source directory (%s) does not exist!" % opts.src)
    sys.exit()

if not os.path.isdir(opts.dest):
    logging.error("Destination directory (%s) does not exist!" % opts.dest)
    sys.exit()

src = os.path.abspath(opts.src)
dest = os.path.abspath(opts.dest)

# lookup = scan(src)

fh = open(opts.csvfile, 'r')
reader = csv.reader(fh)

for row in reader:

    fname = row[0]
    # src_path = lookup.get(fname, None)

    src_path = find(src, fname)

    if not src_path:
        logging.warn("Failed to locate %s anywhere in %s" % (fname, src))
        continue

    if opts.debug:
        logging.info("Debugging is enabled so not copy-ing %s" % path)
        contine

    dest_path = os.path.join(dest, fname)

    logging.info("copy %s to %s" % (src_path, dest_path))
```

hasselblad.csv file detail example:

```
1982-12-7.jpg
1983-14-2.jpg
1984-11-5.jpg
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of move.py? And an example few lines from the CSV?

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import csv
import sys
import logging

def find(src, fname):

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src):

        for f in files:

            logging.debug("compare %s to %s" % (f, fname))

            if f == fname:

                path =  os.path.join(root, f)
                logging.info("%s matches %s" % (path, fname))
                return path

    return None

def scan(src):

    lookup = {}      This is an example of move.py, and the .csv:1963-39-783.jpg  
1963-39-991.jpg  
1948-40-66.jpg  
1953-26-1.jpg

Comment: can you move the comment code back into the question so that it formats properly?  4 spaces before each line

Comment: Hi Joel, thank you for the formatting tip--it makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: Ok, so you said "but it has not worked". Can you post what happened? Did you get an error/traceback? Any log output?